# How should I close tooltip after user submits query with Bootstrap3-Typeahead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I want to provide typeahead functionality by using [bootstrap3-typeahead.js](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) (which is the maintained fork of [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js)) with remote data. However, when the user types quickly and press enter to submit the query, the tooltip still shows up. I thought an easy way to fix this issue was by simply cancelling the ajax request when the user press the enter key. However, this doesn't work.

Based on charlietfl's feedback, this occurs because the request is received before any key is pressed by the user. Therefore, maybe I need another way to remove the tooltip when the user presses the enter key. I would be happy to receive suggestion on how to accomplish that.

This is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dy2LGTobqCccW7PcQAMF?p=preview). If you type, for example, "Dog" quickly and press enter, I'm supposedly aborting the request, but the results are still being shown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var req;
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(
      {
        name: 'animals',
        display: 'value',
        items: 'all',
        delay: 500,
        source: function(query, process) {
                var url = "http://api.gbif.org/v1/species/match?verbose=true&kingdom=Plantae&name=" + query;
                req = $.get(url, function(data) {
                    data =  $.map(data['alternatives'], function(name) {
                        return {
                            name: name['scientificName']
                        };
                    })
                    process(data);
                });

                return req
            }
      })
      .on('keydown', function(event) {
        console.log('keydown');
        if(event.which == 13) {
          console.log('enter key');
          if (req) {
            console.log('req',req);
            req.abort();
          }
        }
      });
});
```

Regards

Comment: Because there is another similar event handler in plugin. It supports keyboard selection. Logic of what you are doing doesn't fit flow of the plugin user input handling

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer a bit more? Did you mean that bootstrap3-typeahead already has an option to cancel a request after certain key press?

Comment: No I mean that the requests are made before anyone hits enter

Comment: I understand. What can I do to not show the suggestions after user submits the query?

Comment: No idea. Not sure why you would need to either

Comment: It is annoying to have suggestions when the user has already received the results. By the way, even after applying a delay of 2 seconds, I still see the same behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116748/discussion-between-robert-smith-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I had to switch to typeahead.js and use its `typeahead('val', '')` feature to clear the input field immediately after the user submits the form. In this way, the suggestions are not shown anymore.

However, this is not an ideal situation since, as I said, typeahead.js doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.

For future reference, the reason I started using bootstrap3-typeahead was because it was easier to setup without including its suggestion engine Bloodhound. Unfortunately, Bloodhound offers the throttling and debouncing methods that is very useful for fetching data from remote sources. Currently, I'm providing similar functionality with this nice trick (source: http://codetunnel.io/how-to-implement-autosave-in-your-web-app/):

```
var timeOutId;

$('.typeahead').typeahead({ // your options
}, {
name: 'someName', 
display: 'value',
source: (query, syncResults, asyncResults) => {
    if (timeoutId) clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            $.get(my_backend + query, function(data) {
                data =  $.map(data.suggestions, function(suggestion) {
                    return {
                        value: suggestion
                    };
                })
                asyncResults(data);
            });
        }, 750);
}})
```